# Finding the Min and Max of User Inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python, and in trying to find out the min and max values of user number inputs, I can't seem to figure it out.

```
count = 0
x = []
while(True):
    x = input('Enter a Number: ')
    high = max(x)
    low = min(x)
    if(x.isdigit()):
        count += 1
    else:
        print("Your Highest Number is: " + high)
        print("Your Lowest Number is: " + low)
        break
```

Comment: Can you please provide a typical user input and respective expected output? What is currently happening that isn't working out for you?

Comment: Side-note: Python doesn't require conditional/looping constructs to be wrapped in parens, don't use them unless there is a precedence issue that they resolve. `while True:` is cleaner/more Pythonic than `while(True):` and `if x.isdigit():` is similarly better than `if(x.isdigit()):`.

Answer (score 1):

break your program into small manageable chunks start with just a simple function to get the number

```
def input_number(prompt="Enter A Number:"):
    while True:
         try: return int(input(prompt))
         except ValueError:
             if not input: return None #user is done
             else: print("That's not an integer!")
```

then write a function to continue getting numbers from the user until they are done entering numbers

```
def get_minmax_numbers(prompt="Enter A Number: "):
   maxN = None
   minN = None
   tmp = input_number(prompt)
   while tmp is not None: #keep asking until the user enters nothing
        maxN = tmp if maxN is None else max(tmp,maxN)
        minN = tmp if minN is None else min(tmp,minN)
        tmp = input_number(prompt) # get next number
   return minN, maxN
```

then just put them together

```
 print("Enter Nothing when you are finished!")
 min_and_max = get_numbers()
 print("You entered Min of {0} and Max of {1}".format(*min_and_max)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
inp=input("enter values seperated by space")
x=[int(x) for x in inp.split(" ")]
print (min(x))
print (max(x))
```

output:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

enter values seperated by space 20 1 55 90 44
1
90
```

Comment: he is using python3 ... raw_input does not work in python3

Comment: @JoranBeasley Done!

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a list, and to append an item to a list, you must call the `append` method on the list, rather than directly assigning an item to the list, which would override the list with that item.

Code:

```
count = 0
x = []
while(True):
    num = input('Enter a Number: ')
    if(num.isdigit()):
        x.append(int(num))
        count += 1
    elif(x):
        high = max(x)
        low = min(x)
        print("Your Highest Number is: " + str(high))
        print("Your Lowest Number is: " + str(low))
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter some numbers")
        break
```